# Is it possible to group data by value in Grafana with Prometheus datasource?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I've a Prometheus datasource which contains the filling percentage of hundred filesystem.

These % can be any value from 0 to 99%, but I want to monitor them by range (0 to 25%, 25 to 50%, ...)

I read that Prometheus accept range vector based on a time range (== a duration), but I don't see anything about range of value.

Is there any operator or function which deals with range of value, or should I manually create subdataset? Or is there any other bypass?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see values of you metric only between 0.25 and 0.5 you can use query

```
my_metric{my_label="l1"} > 0.25 < 0.5
```